# svn resource path

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

subeclipse on Eclipse4.2
I want go create a tag v1.1, but the path is `/tags/v1.1/xxxxx` not `/tags/v1.1`
why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue for the past week or so however I have just installed a new update via Help -> Check for Updates and this has fixed it for me.